# Parse jsonObject from android and get it in webservice vb.net

Tags: java, android, json, vb.net, wcf

I have resolved the problem,

I think my problem is I don't know how to get JSON in webservice .NET

I use android studio for parse JSON Object to my webservice, the JSON Array and JSON Object is working,

but I got a bad request (maybe because I can't get JSON in webservice?)

```
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("horary", jsonArray);
            URL url = new URL("URL");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(4000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF-8"));
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            Log.d("json", conn.getResponseMessage());<- bad Request
```

Here is my code from webservice vb.net. I don't know how to get the JSON object

```
     <WebInvoke(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="Change/")>
        Function HReceiver(horary As String) As String Implements IService.HReceiver
```

I suppose I get the JSON with (horary As String) and I try many ways to deserialize,

but it's not the point, because I suppose I can't get JSON

```
            Dim ser As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim horary As ArrayHorary
            Dim result As String
            Try
                Dim items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ArrayHorary())(horary)
                result = horary.ToString
            Catch ex As Exception
                result = ex.ToString
            End Try
            Return result
        End Function

        Public Class ArrayHorary
            Public Property id As String
            Public Property name As String
        End Class
```

Thanks for the time

------------I Resolved With

```
<OperationContract()>
    Function HReceiver(horary As Horar) As String

    <DataContract()>
Public Class Horar
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property horary As List(Of Horari)
End Class

    <DataContract()>
Public Class Horari
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property id As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property name As String

End Class
```

in Service

```
<WebInvoke(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="Change/")>
    Function HReceiver(horar As Horar) As String Implements IService.HReceiver
        Dim result As String

        result = horar.horary(0).name
return result
```

and this work without deserializer

in android, I must use

```
os.writeChars(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To recive a JSON object in a proper way you have to have a class with the same structure as a function parameter, for example if you are receiving a list of this object you api parameter should  be:

```
Function SpoolsList(objVar As List(Of ArrayHorary)) As IHttpActionResult
    Your code
End Function
```

Then it will parse the object automatically.

Comment: thanks, so i need to repalce (horary As String) and add this method in interface and add too ArrayHorary in interface like <DataContract()>

Comment: Try always to receive the JSON object with a proper class this will save you a hell of time and the .net will do the work for you you just use the class object as is.

Comment: if this answer helped you, mark it as correct so others can benefit from it.

Comment: when i use objVar As Array / or arraylist, i get "0" in length, looks like i don't have anything in objVar